# Microsoft Sync Framework Not synchronizing Azure database with local SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync framework to synchronize an Azure database with a local SQL Server 2008 database. Everything is working fine. But I have a small problem as mentioned below

I am synchronizing in one way (ie) from Azure DB to local DB. Insert/update/delete on Azure DB gets synchronized with local database. But I tried to manually update a record in local DB using normal update statement. Also I updated the same record with corresponding new value in the Azure DB. Now the record in the local DB is not getting the updated value from the Azure DB. This problem happens only after updating a record manually in local database.

Please help anyone.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you're now encountering a conflict. when both copy of a row is updated on both ends, you end up with a conflict and you need to tell Sync Framework how to resolve it (e.g., Retain local copy or overwrite it)

see: [How to: Handle Data Conflicts and Errors for Database Synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/subscriptions/ff928697.aspx)